# PHP base64_encode dont work correctly

Tags: php, base64

I have a problem for encoding my data to base64 in php. I want to encode my mail subject which is in Persian with base64_encode function. but I didn't get expected result. I started to test my base64_encode function.

when I converted 'سلام' with PHP the result was '0+HH4w==' and when I tested same thing in http://www.base64encode.org/ web site the result was '2LPZhNin2YU='.
I tried base64_decode('2LPZhNin2YU=') and the output was 'سلام'

do anybody know why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'0+HH4w==' is CP1256 (a.k.a. Windows-1256 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256) while '2LPZhNin2YU=' is UTF8.

Just set the charset of your script to windows-1256 and everything should be OK.

Comment: do you know how can I do that? should I make changes in php.ini file? :)

Comment: Can you post the script you have somewhere? (Pastebin.com for exapmle)

Comment: I googled for it but I couldn't find anything for changing character set for base64_encode function. all I found was for connecting to DB or setting character set for Page itself.

Comment: my test file just contain two lines :D `$m=base64_encode('سلام');
print $m;`

Comment: adding this header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1256\n"), was this what you talking about? In my case, base_64encode returns null. I have sending in the correct base-64 but I don't think I downloaded something right. If you know what I have to download please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is not the `base64_encode()` function, that is creating your problem, but the processing before: Remember, that a string needs **2** ingredients to hold meaningfull text: **encoding and bytestream**. Judging from the base64-encoded values, you lost your UTF8-Encoding on the string, transforming it into some windows codepage encoding.